# Does if (obj.nonExistentProperty) trigger any browser errors?

Tags: javascript, definition, typeof, hasownproperty

I'm iterating through an array of simple (JSON-style) objects, some of which have a given property, and some that don't. If they have that property, *it's safe to assume that it will never evaluate to a falsy value.*

```
var objs = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 5},
    {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}
];
```

My rather large application is triggering some (very unhelpful) errors in Internet Explorer 8, so I just want to cross this off the list of potential issues. Is it safe to use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; ++i) {
    if (objs[i].c) {
        // objs[i].c is defined
    }
}
```

I've used this sort of check many times in the application code, but do I need to be using `obj.hasOwnProperty('c')` or `typeof obj.c != 'undefined'`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... it's safe to assume that it will never evaluate to a falsy value.

No, it's not safe. If you'd have an object like `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}`, `objs[i].c` will be evaluated falsy. (Or `c` equals to `false`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined` or `''`.)

If you want just to know, if there's a property defined in an object, you can do `'c' in objs[i]`, but beware, this will also include properties from the prototype chain.

If you want to avoid getting properties from the prototype chain, `hasOwnProperty` check needs to be done.

There's also [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) available in modern browsers, though it's not handy on quick-checks.

Comment: I was only interested in knowing if it triggered browser errors. It *is* safe to assume that the values I will give to `c` will never be falsy values, i.e. the property I am testing will never be `false`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or `''` -- or, if it is any of those, I will treat it the same as if it were not defined.

Comment: Looks like I've misunderstood you question. Anyway, There should not be problems when checking a non-existing property of object in IE. No errors should occur, no matter what value a prop has, or if it even doesn't exist. Probably something else causes errors in your code. What exactly are "`very unhelpful`" error messages?

Comment: It appears to be unrelated. It's a very large, AJAX-driven application, most of which I didn't develop.

Answer (score 1):

I think below one is good to check that particular object has a property. I also used this method on web application frequently.

```
 obj.hasOwnProperty('c')
```